# OpenGL vertex shader for pinhole camera model

Tags: opengl, geometry, glsl

I am trying to implement a simple OpenGL renderer that simulates a pinhole camera model (as defined for example [here](http://ksimek.github.io/2013/08/13/intrinsic/)). Currently I use the vertex shader to map the 3D vertices to the clip space, where K in the shader contains [focal length x, focal length y, principal point x, principal point y] and zrange is the depth range of the vertices.

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 vin;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 cin;
layout (location = 2) in vec3 nin;

out vec3 shader_pos;
out vec3 shader_color;
out vec3 shader_normal;

uniform vec4 K;
uniform vec2 zrange;
uniform vec2 imsize;

void main() {
  vec3 uvd;
  uvd.x = (K[0] * vin.x + K[2] * vin.z) / vin.z;
  uvd.y = (K[1] * vin.y + K[3] * vin.z) / vin.z;
  uvd.x = 2 * uvd.x / (imsize[0]) - 1;
  uvd.y = 2 * uvd.y / (imsize[1]) - 1;
  uvd.z = 2 * (vin.z - zrange[0]) / (zrange[1] - zrange[0]) - 1;
  shader_pos = uvd;
  shader_color = cin;
  shader_normal = nin;
  gl_Position = vec4(uvd.xyz, 1.0);
}
```

I verify the renderings with a simple ray-tracer, however there seems to be an offset stemming from my OpenGL implementation. The depth values are different, but not by an affine offset as it would be caused by a wrong remapping (see the slanted surface on the tetrahedron, ignoring the errors on the edges).
[image: Error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am trying to implement a simple OpenGL renderer that simulates a pinhole camera model.

A standard perspective projection matrix already implements a pinhole camera model. What you're doing here is just having more calculations per vertex, which could all be pre-calculated on the CPU and put in a single matrix.

The only difference is the `z` range. But a "pinhole camera" does not have a `z` range, all points are projected to the image plane. So what you want here is a pinhole camera model for `x` and `y`, and a *linear* mapping for `z`.

However, your implementation is wrong. A GPU will interpolate the `z` linearly **in window space**. That means, it will calculate the barycentric coordinates of each fragment with respect to the **2D projection** of the triangle of the window. However, when using a perspective projection, and when the triangle is not excatly parallel to the image plane, those barycentric coordinates will not be those the respective 3D point would have had with respect to the *actual 3D primitive* before the projection.

The trick here is that since in screen space, we typically have `x/z` and `y/z` as the vertex coordinates, and when we interpolate linaerily inbetween that, we also have to interpolate `1/z` for the depth. However, in reality, we don't divide by `z`, but `w` (and let the projection matrix set `w_clip = [+/-]z_eye` for us). After the division by `w_clip`, we get a *hyperbolic* mapping of the `z` value, but with the nice property that it can be linearly interpolated in window space.

What this means is that by your use of a linear `z` mapping, your primitives now would have to be *bend* along the `z` dimension to get the correct result. Look at the following top-down view of the situation. The "lines" represent flat triangles, looked from straight above:

[image: visualization of hyperbolic z versus linear z]

In eye space, the view rays would all go from the origin through each pixel (we could imagine the 2D pixel raster on the near plane, for example). In NDC, we have transformed this to an *orthograhic projection*. The pixels still can be imagined at the near plane, but all view rays now are *parallel*.

In the standard hyperbolical mapping, the point in the middle of the frustum is compressed much towards the end. However, the traingle still is flat.

If you use a linear mapping instead, your triangle would have not to be flat any more. Look for example at the intersection point between the two traingles. It must have the same `x` (and `y`) coordinate as in the hyperbolic case, for the correct result.

However, you only transform the vertices according to a linear z value, the GPU will still linearly interpolate the result, so in your case, you would get straight connections between your transformed points, your intersection point between the two triangles is moved, and your depth values are all wrong except for the actual vertex points itself.

*If* you want to use a linear depth buffer, you have to correct the depth of each fragment in the fragment shader, to implement the required non-linear interpolation on your own. Doing so would break a lot of the clever depth test optimizations GPUs do, notably early Z and hierachical Z, so while it is possible, you'l loose some performance.

The much better solution is: Just use a standard hyperbolic depth value. Just linearize the depth values after you read them back. Also, don't do the `z` Division in the vertex shader. You do not only break `z` this way, you also break the perspective-corrected interpolation of the varyings, so your shading will also be wrong. Let the GPU do the division, just shuffle the correct value into `gl_Position.w`. The GPU will internally not only do the divide, the perspective corrected interpolation also depends on `w`.